# Affine GIT quotients and the excursion algebra in Fargues–Scholze

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, moduli-spaces, langlands-conjectures, geometric-invariant-theory

**Some background:**

Let us fix a non-archimedean local field $E$ with residue characteristic $p$, and let $G$ be some connected reductive group over $E$. In [FS, §VIII.1.1] the authors define a moduli sheaf $Z^1(W_E,\widehat{G})$ of condensed $1$-cocycles for $\widehat{G}$ on $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-schemes for $\ell\ne p$ (also defined by other authors). They show that this moduli space is representable with affine connected components.

More precisely, they first observe that

$$Z^1(W_E,\widehat{G})=\varinjlim_P Z^1(W_E/P,\widehat{G})$$

where here $P$ travels over open (normal) subgroups of the wild inertia group $P_E$ for $W_E$, and the transition maps are clopen. They then observe that, for a fixed $P$, one has that $Z^1(W_E/P,\widehat{G})= Z^1(W,\widehat{G})$ where $W\subseteq W_E/P$  is the discrete subgroup generated by the image of $P_E$ and choices of generators for tame inertia and a Frobenius. They then show that $Z^1(W,\widehat{G})$ is represented by an affine $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-scheme which is finite type, flat, and a relative complete intersection.

$\DeclareMathOperator\colim{colim}$Wishing to study the affine GIT quotient(s) $Z^1(W,\widehat{G})\mathbin{//}\widehat{G}$ Fargues and Scholze observe that there is a $\widehat{G}$-equivariant identification
$$\mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))=\colim_{\mathcal{J}}\,\mathcal{O}(Z^1(F_n,\widehat{G}))\tag{1}\label{1}$$

(where here $\mathcal{O}$ just means global sections of the structure sheaf). Here $\mathcal{J}$ is the category of all pairs $(n,\iota)$ where $n\geqslant 0$ is an integer and $\iota\colon F_n\to W$ is a group map. This identification is nearly tautological. From this we immediately see that one has an identification
$$\mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}=\left(\colim_\mathcal{J} \,\mathcal{O}(Z^1(F_n,\widehat{G}))\right)^\widehat{G}.$$

$\DeclareMathOperator\Exc{Exc}$They then consider the *excursion algebra*

$$\Exc(W,\widehat{G}):=\mathrm{colim}_\mathcal{J}\, \mathcal{O}(Z^1(F_n,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}},$$

and observe that one tautologically has a map of $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-algebras $\Exc(W,\widehat{G})\to \mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$.

**The question**

Fargues and Scholze make the following claim:

> **Claim:** The map $\Exc(W,\widehat{G})\to \mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$ induces a universal homeomorphism (of discrete $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-schemes) and induces an isomorphism over $\mathbb{Q}_\ell$.

Their justification for this is that it follows from [H], but I am not sure how. As they give no further explanation, I would assume the reason is simple, and I am missing it.

**One (possibly overcomplicated) explanation**

$\DeclareMathOperator\Spec{Spec}$If I have not made a mistake, there is one way to justify this using the material in [A]. Namely, in op. cit. the author defines a ring map $A\to B$ to be *adequate* (resp. *universally adequate*) if for every $b$ in $B$ there exists some $N\geqslant 1$ and some $a$ in $A$ such that $a\mapsto b^N$ (resp. is adequate after every base change). He also then proves the following fact.

> **Fact 1 ([A, Lemma 3.14 and Lemma 3.15]):** Let $A\to B$ be an injective (universally) adequate morphism. Then, $\Spec(B)\to \Spec(A)$ is a (universal) homeomorphism, and is an isomorphism if $A$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra.

From this we see that to prove the above stated claim of Fargues and Scholze it suffices to show that $\Exc(W,\widehat{G})\to \mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$ is an injective universally adequate map. Injectivity is clear (cf. [B, Theorem 1]) and so it suffices to prove the map is universally adequate.

To prove this, one can use the following result in [A].

> **Fact 2 (cf. [A, Lemma 9.2.5]):** Suppose that $H\to\Spec(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ is a geometrically reductive group scheme. If $A\to B$ is a surjection of finite type $\mathbb{Z}_\ell[H]$-algebras, then the induced map $A^H\to B^H$ is universally adequate.

I won't define what geometrically reductive means, but the results of Haboush and Seshadri (I assume that's what the reference to [H] was about, but I thought it would be more relevant to cite [S]) imply that as $\widehat{G}\to \Spec(\mathbb{Z}_\ell)$ is connected and reductive it is geometrically reductive.

Now, as $\mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))$ is finite type over $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$, it's easy to see from \eqref{1} that $\mathcal{O}(Z^1(F_n,\widehat{G}))\to \mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))$ is surjective for some $(n,\iota)$. We may then apply Fact 2 to see that $\mathcal{O}(Z^1(F_n,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}\to \mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$ is universally adequate, and from this it follows fairly quickly that $\Exc(W,\widehat{G})\to \mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$ is universally adequate, and so again we're done by Fact 1.

---

Is my explanation of this correct? Is there a simpler way to understand the proof of the claim?

I apologize if I have overcomplicated things.

**References:**

[A] Alper, J., 2014. [Adequate moduli spaces and geometrically reductive group schemes](https://doi.org/10.14231/AG-2014-022).

[B] Bergman, G.M., 2005. [Direct limits and fixed point sets](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2005.08.002). Journal of Algebra, 292(2), pp.592-614.

[FS] Fargues, L. and Scholze, P., 2021. [Geometrization of the local Langlands correspondence](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.13459). arXiv preprint arXiv:2102.13459.

[H] Haboush, W.J., 1975. [Reductive groups are geometrically reductive](https://doi.org/10.2307/1970974). Annals of Mathematics, 102(1), pp.67-83.

[S] Seshadri, C.S., 1977. [Geometric reductivity over arbitrary base](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-8708(77)90041-X). Advances in Mathematics, 26(3), pp.225-274.

Comment: Sorry do you mean Lemma 9.2.5 of Jarod's paper?

Comment: It seems to me that perhaps Scholze-Fargues are alluding to the fact that $\widehat{G}$ being geometrically reductive (by Haboush's theorem) implies that $\text{Exc}(W, \widehat{G})$ and $\mathcal{O}(Z^1(W, \widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$ are finite type $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-algebras? If you have this result, then I believe you can get things like the map in your question being finite and surjective easily. I don't quite see why it's radicial yet (without reasoning as you did above).

Comment: At any rate, I don't see how Haboush's result implies that $\text{Exc}(W,\widehat{G}$ and $\mathcal{O}(Z^1(W,\widehat{G}))^{\widehat{G}}$ are f.t. The reason for this is that Mumford's result on the finite generation of rings of invariants is only when the base is a field, and here our base is $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$! One needs to use Theorem 6.3.3 of Jarod's adequate moduli spaces paper to conclude this.

Comment: Sorry for being cryptic here! After inverting $\ell$, taking $\hat{G}$-invariants is exact, so the result is clear. Also, taking $\hat{G}$-invariants preserves finite type $\mathbb Z_\ell$-algebras; I gather I missed the good reference for that. Then to prove that it's a universal homeomorphism, it suffices to identify $\overline{\mathbb F}_\ell$-points. These correspond, by Haboush, to closed $\hat{G}$-orbits of the algebras base changed to $\overline{\mathbb F}_\ell$. But these closed $\hat{G}$-orbits can be identified easily.

Comment: @DavidBenjaminLim Hey man. Thanks for taking the time to read my post! I agree that it seems, in any case, that Alper's paper (or maybe at least Seshadri?) is needed here. Also, thanks for the typo -- I have fixed the lemma number.

Comment: @PeterScholze Hey Peter, thanks for your quick response! On the generic fiber I agree things are simple. For the claim about universal homeomorphism, I am still slightly confused, but am probably just being thick. They are finite type $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-algebras (from the strengthening of Mumford's theorem alluded to above) so for universal bijectivity it's reasonable that we need only check on $\overline{\mathbb{F}}_\ell$-points. But, I don't see how we're getting the homeomorphism part. Above it was suggested this map is obviously finite --this is the key basic thing I am missing.

Comment: @PeterScholze Also, does one need Haboush's theroem to say that the closed points on on the affine GIT quotient correspond to closed orbits on the original? Doesn't that follow from general GIT nonsense? Even then I need to think of why the comparison is clear -- we're claiming that for a colimit of algebras the closed orbits of the colimits are the colimit of the closed orbits. This is probably simple, and I will think on it. Thanks again!

Comment: Let $A=\mathcal O(Z^1(W,\hat{G}))$ and $B=\mathcal O(Z^1(F_n,\hat{G}))$ for some surjection $F_n\to W$. Then the closed $\hat{G}$-orbits in $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ inject into the closed $\hat{G}$-orbits in $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$. Conversely, a closed $\hat{G}$-orbit in $\mathrm{Spec}(B)$ which extends to a compatible system of closed $\hat{G}$-orbits in all other $B'$'s, necessarily lives in $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ (as all its closed points do, as $A$ is the colimit of the $B'$'s).

Comment: About Haboush: I think this is the key theorem to justify this correspondence to closed $\hat{G}$-orbits. (It guarantees that there are enough $\hat{G}$-invariant functions to distinguish between any two distinct closed $\hat{G}$-orbits.)

Comment: @PeterScholze Hmm, OK. Yeah, you might be right -- I perhaps forgot what Mumford assumed when he talked about these things. In any case, many thanks. I'll think carefully about what you suggested.

Comment: You may find my expository paper Reductivity properties over an affine base,
Indagationes Mathematicae (2020),  https://doi.org/10.1016/j.indag.2020.09.009 helpful.

Comment: @WilberdvanderKallen Hey Wilberd, this does seem to be a useful collection of results! Can you clarify how it helps precisely though? It seems as though what you call 'power surjective' is what Alper calls 'adequate' and so one can use results in your paper in lieu of Alpers to argue as I did in the main body of the question. Is that what you meant, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: @PeterScholze, would you promote your comments to an answer?

Comment: @AlexYoucis Yes, I was thinking of using 'power reductivity' (='adequate'), and the fact that Mumford's conjecture is now known in such generality that one does not need to consult Haboush or Seshadri when checking conditions.

Comment: @AlexYoucis Here's a stacky interpretation of what Peter is saying. Big caveat: I do not know any $2$-categorical or $\infty$ stuff, so what I'm saying might be pure nonsense. Let me now just work over $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_\ell$. By Haboush's theorem (that reductive is geometrically reductive), we are now in the land of adequate moduli spaces. In other words, we can say that the map of algebraic stacks $\varprojlim [\operatorname{Spec} B_n/\widehat{G}] \to [\operatorname{Spec} A /\widehat{G}]$

Comment: (cont'd) induces a map of adequate moduli spaces that is exactly the Spec of the map in your question. We want to know what the $\overline{\mathbf{F}}_\ell$ points of these adequate moduli spaces look like. But these correspond exactly to closed points of the stacks upstairs (Theorem 5.3.1 (5) of Jarod's paper). What is a closed point the quotient $[\operatorname{Spec} A/\widehat{G}]$? Exactly a closed $\widehat{G}$-orbit! This I believe is what Peter was trying to get at. Now I just need to figure out what the "inverse limit of algebraic stacks" even means....